# MySQL Error 1265 Data Truncated for Enum

Tags: mysql, enums

I have a stored procedure in MySQL that has an enum called log_level with a few values.

```
..

DECLARE log_level ENUM('none','some','errors','debug') DEFAULT 1;

SET log_level = 0; 

..
```

Gives the error:

[image]

If I change this to:

```
..

DECLARE log_level ENUM('none','some','errors','debug') DEFAULT log_level=1;

SET log_level = 0; 

..
```

It gives the error:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Same kind issue was occurring with me when i was doing `

> ALTER`or`INSERT

` the information.

I got fixed by

> `UPDATE TABLE t SET t.fieldName = NULL`

and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL enums work differently than the C/C++ equivalent. `log_level` is declared as an enum of strings so it really expects a string as value. A default of '1' doesn't make much sense, either.

The correct syntax is:

```
DECLARE log_level ENUM('none','some','errors','debug') DEFAULT 'some';

SET log_level = 'none';
```

The same error 1265 shows up if you try to assign a non-existing value to an enum (e.g. an empty string in stead of a real NULL value).

Sidenote: internally the database uses integer values but those details are completely hidden by the SQL language.